# Is there a better way to convert a list to a dictionary in Python with keys but no values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I was sure that there would be a one liner to convert a list to a dictionary where the items in the list were keys and the dictionary had no values.

The only way I could find to do it was argued against.

"Using list comprehensions when the result is ignored is misleading and inefficient. A `for` loop is better"

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d']
myDict = {}
x=[myDict.update({item:None}) for item in myList]

>>> myDict
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None, 'd': None}
```

It works, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Keys with no values?  Isn't that a set?

Comment: Humm, I just figured out that I can pickle a set so maybe I will use a set but now I have to go make sure that I can look up a value in a set as fast as I can a value in a dictionary and I can tell my wife wants me to stop working and come home.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Membership testing in sets is basically equivalent to key lookup in dictionaries (both use hashes).  More importantly, if you are going to be doing set operations (union, intersection, difference, etc.), then it's easier and faster to do them with sets than with dictionaries.

Comment: @S.Lott when searching an item in a dict gives you O(1) access time while urordered sets(by default) gives you O(n) and ordered sets(that which you have sort, aka additional computational cost) gives you O(logn).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dict.fromkeys(my_list)
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Values default to `None`, but you can specify them as an optional argument:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dict.fromkeys(my_list, 0)
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
```

From the docs:

> a.fromkeys(seq[, value]) Creates a new
>   dictionary with keys from seq and
>   values set to value.
>
> dict.fromkeys is a class method that
>   returns a new dictionary. value
>   defaults to None. New in version 2.3.

Answer (score 15):

You could use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a dict:

```
>>> myList=['a','b','c','d']
>>> set(myList)
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

This is better if you never need to store values, and are just storing an unordered collection of unique items.

Comment: Plus `set` consumes less memory (one less pointer per set item, or 33% savings). Also check out `frozenset`, a const (immutable) version of set. There are no performance benefits to `frozenset`, but it makes the program logic cleaner.

Comment: when searching an item in a dict gives you O(1) access time while urordered sets(by default) gives you O(n) and ordered sets(that which you have sort, aka additional computational cost) gives you O(logn).

Answer (score 5):

To answer the original questioner's performance worries (for lookups in `dict` vs `set`), somewhat surprisingly, `dict` lookups *can* be minutely faster (in Python 2.5.1 on my rather slow laptop) assuming for example that half the lookups fail and half succeed. Here's how one goes about finding out:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'k=dict.fromkeys(range(99))' '5 in k and 112 in k'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.236 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'k=set(range(99))' '5 in k and 112 in k'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.265 usec per loop
```

doing each check several times to verify they're repeatable. So, if those 30 nanoseconds or less on a slow laptop are in an absolutely crucial bottleneck, it may be worth going for the obscure `dict.fromkeys` solution rather than the simple, obvious, readable, and clearly correct `set` (unusual -- almost invariably in Python the simple and direct solution has performance advantages too).

Of course, one needs to check with one's own Python version, machine, data, and ratio of successful vs failing tests, **and** confirm with extremely accurate profiling that shaving 30 nanoseconds (or whatever) off this lookup will make an important difference.

Fortunately, in the vast majority of cases, this will prove totally unnecessary... but since programmers **will** obsess about meaningless micro-optimizations *anyway*, no matter how many times they're told about their irrelevance, the `timeit` module is right there in the standard library to make those mostly-meaningless micro-benchmarks easy as pie anyway!-)

Comment: This is an awesome comment. Every developer obsesses with micro-optimizations must be made to read it over and over again.  Reminds me of "(unrolling of far loop, for better performance)[http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8ozon/how_to_write_unmaintainable_code_a_stepbystep/c09zh2a]"

Comment: Not true on (C)Python2.5: set is faster **both** to build and to query with `in`. It also consumes 33% less memory, something that hasn't been mentioned here yet.

Answer (score 1):

And here's a fairly wrong and inefficient way to do it using map:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> map (lambda x: d.__setitem__(x, None), [1,2,3])
[None, None, None]
>>> d
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d']
my_dict = dict([(ele, None) for ele in my_list])
```

Comment: You can also use a generator comprehension (just drop the square brackets!)

In Python 3.0, there are even dict comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use itertools:

```
>>>import itertools
>>>my_list = ['a','b','c','d']
>>>d = {}
>>>for x in itertools.imap(d.setdefault, my_list): pass
>>>print d
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None, 'd': None}
```

For huge lists, maybe this is very good :P

Comment: Tip: highlight your code and press ctrl-k to get syntax highlighting and preserve proper indentation.